# E minor to A minor transiton with F#

Tags: guitar, scales

I'm learning guitar and have been practicing transitions between chords using notes in common for the key/scale.

One lesson starts with A minor for one measure and then transitions to D minor by playing the individual notes A A B C, and then the D minor for one measure.  Going back to A minor uses D D C B and then the A minor chord for one measure, then to E minor with A A G F.  Something like this:

Amin | A A B C | D Dmin | D D C B | A Amin | A A G F | E Emin | E E F G | A Amin |

While practicing, I really don't like the sound of the F in the transition between Amin and Emin, and started playing F# instead of F.  I really like this sound, but I cannot find what it is.  To my ears, it sounds much more appealing and I would think this has a name, but I cannot seem to find anything.  Of course, it could just be an F# in my A minor progression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing with F is the a- **aeolian** scale.

Playing with F♯ is a **dorian**

It seems you feel more “at home” in the dorian scale.

Comment: Yes, Dorian sounds much better to my ear for some reason.  I also realized that this is a flat 5 of the relative major, Cmaj.  Music theory is so fascinating!

Comment: @KirkD-CO - some would say it's *not* the b5 of C. It's the #4. The b5 would have to be called Gb. Same note, same sound, different name. Theory!

Comment: @Tim - I have so much to learn! Thanks for the comment and answer.

Answer (score 1):

The 'key* of A minor contains more than the usual 7 notes found in usual scales. When people write in Am, they use notes A, B, C, D, E, F, F♯, G, G♯.

Those extra notes show themselves in different minor *scales* and *modes*. The two Fs and two Gs are options which lend themselves to different situations, and are indeed options. Choose which you prefer. You might even like using G♯ instead of G to get back to Am. It is used very often.

Things to check out:

Natural minor

Harmonic minor

Melodic minor

Dorian mode

Phrygian mode.